# JavaScript inheritance example returning undefined

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I copied most of the code from an MDN [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) on `.create()` with some slight modification:

```
// superclass
function Shape() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
};

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function( x, y ) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// subclass
function Rectangle() {
    Shape.call(this); // call super constructor passing the current object
}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create( Shape.prototype );

var rect = new Rectangle();

console.log( rect.move( 1, 1 ) );
```

Output:

```
Shape moved
undefined
```

Why is it getting `undefined` also?

Comment: what do you expect to be logged in the second statement

Comment: Because that is what is "returned" by the function, nothing, so it is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript a function always returns undefined if no return value is specified. The move function does not return anything. So logging its output logs undefined.